# Reading local file from absolute path in node fs module

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, electron, fs

I am trying to read a file from local system using  node js 'fs' module. But for some reason, the 'fs' module is not working when I pass absolute path.

Code:

```
let filePath = "/home/mysystem/dev/myproject/sayHello.txt";
let newFile=fs.readFileSync('file://'+filePath);
```

The code is throwing an error as:

```
Uncaught Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'file:///home/mysystem/dev/myproject/sayHello.txt'
```

But I can open the file from browser window using the same path.
fs module is working if I pass relative path. I am using this inside an app built using electron framework.

Comment: You don't need the `file` protocol for NodeJS. Simply try read `filePath` without the `"file://"`

Comment: Thanks man! . I was trying to solve this for a long time.  :)

Comment: @zfor Can you convert your comment to an answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In NodeJS you don't have to use the `file` protocol for reading files.

You can get rid of the `"file://"` part and try read the `filePath` directly

```
let filePath = "/home/mysystem/dev/myproject/sayHello.txt";
let newFile = fs.readFileSync(filePath);
```

Answer (score 2):

I got stumped with this for a bit. If using Angular 2 and Typescript on Windows, your absolute path will look like this:

```
import { readdirSync } from "fs";
. . .
let x = readdirSync("C:/SAFE/Dir1/Blah");
console.log("files retrieved="+ x.length);
```