# Upload a pdf file from Downloads folder to firebase storage

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

In my app creates a PDF and stores it in Documents folder.   I want to take that file and upload to firebase storage.  I am able to get a file to storage but I believe it's empty as it is only 9B in size.  I really think file defined below as:

const file = "C:/Users/greta/Downloads/" + UnivFields.holdCoupImage;

is incorrect.   I assumed it would be the path of the file to load.  I see all examples have file but I have yet to find any of the examples where file is actually defined.

```
async function savePdfToFS() {

const storage = getStorage();

// Create the file metadata
/** @type {any} */
const metadata = {
  contentType: 'application/pdf' 
};              

// Upload file and metadata to the object 

const file = "C:/Users/greta/Downloads/" + UnivFields.holdCoupImage;//I think this may be the problem

const storageRef = ref(storage, 'images/' + UnivFields.holdCoupImage);
//const storageRef = ref(storage, file);
const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, file, metadata);

//const uploadTask = storage.put(file);
// Listen for state changes, errors, and completion of the upload.
await uploadTask.on('state_changed',
  (snapshot) => {
    // Get task progress, including the number of bytes uploaded and the total number of bytes to be uploaded
    const progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
    console.log('Upload is ' + progress + '% done');
    switch (snapshot.state) {
      case 'paused':
        console.log('Upload is paused');
        break;
      case 'running':
        console.log('Upload is running');
        break;
    }
  }, 
  (error) => {
    // A full list of error codes is available at
    // https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/handle-errors
    switch (error.code) {
      case 'storage/unauthorized':
        // User doesn't have permission to access the object
        break;
      case 'storage/canceled':
        // User canceled the upload
        break;

      // ...

      case 'storage/unknown':
        // Unknown error occurred, inspect error.serverResponse
        break;
    }
  }, 
  () => {
    // Upload completed successfully, now we can get the download URL
    getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then((downloadURL) => {
      console.log('File available at', downloadURL);
    });
  }
);
}
```

Comment: In the code you’ve shared above, the variable `file` is a string referencing a path on a (ostensibly local) filesystem. You’re then passing it to the `data` parameter of [`uploadBytesResumable()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/storage.md#uploadbytesresumable). If you read the linked docs, the content of that parameter is intended to be “*the data to upload*”, not a string representing a path. You’ll need to read the contents of the file itself to a variable of an appropriate type, and pass that to this parameter.

Comment: Be forewarned that this isn’t always a trivial task in a browser based environment, as access into local file systems from this execution context have been traditionally limited in the name of security.

Comment: esqew.   Thank you for the reply.   I knew that was probably the issue.  But I have not seen any examples of how this data is defined.   I will keep looking but thanks again at least I know what he issue is

Comment: "*I have not seen any examples of how this data is defined.*" It's supposed to be binary data or raw bytes comprising the file in question, represented by an object typed as either a `Blob`, `Uint8Array`, or `ArrayBuffer`. Check the documentation I linked above

Comment: I linked a question on how this error comes to be, which is indeed as @esqew said that you're uploading the file path rather than its contents. On how to read a local file on Windows, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38698121/reading-local-file-from-absolute-path-in-node-fs-module and more from these [search results](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+node.js+read+local+file+on+windows).